# Wrong press and get things dark in blender 3.4.1

Tags: eevee-render-engine, sculpting

So, I am sculpting something else but press the wrong button and can't return. Does anyone know what this is, the mode, or some functions that I don't know? I am new to Blender.[image: Get things dark]

Comment: Without knowing where you want to be it's hard to tell how to get you back.

Obviously, you are in sculpt mode here. What's wrong with what you have here?
What is it what you wanted to have instead?

Comment: Maybe it's the mesh display you're currently in that you don't want, and you want to return to the shaded viewport display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you mean may be the mesh view, and you want to go back to the shaded viewport.
If it's that, you pressed the button marked red in the figure. To go back to shaded view, press the one marked green, which is the standard view in sculpt mode for a reason.
[image]
You can also try out the other two buttons right to it, which will give you a preview rendered by the EEVEE-engine or even the Cycles engine, but, indeed, there is a reason for sculpt mode beeing in viewport shading, as you tend to get very dense models , and EEVEE or Cycles rendering may become slow.

Comment: Yes, that's it , thanks you so much

Comment: You probably pressed Shift-Z which toggles in and out of viewport Wireframe view in Blender. Z on its own brings up the pie menu to select the viewport display.

Comment: Yes, I pressed shift-z. The Material Preview Mode is extremely nice.